# Numeric input in Power BI with min and max

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm doing some custom R HTML visuals in Power BI. I can get a number input in Power BI by adding

```
    "TestNumeric": {
      "displayName": "Number",
      "description": "test number",
      "type": {
        "numeric": true
      }
    }
```

in ***capabilities.json*** (and adapting ***src/settings.ts*** accordingly).

I would like to constrain this number input with a minimum and a maximum value. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. One has to modify the file ***src/visual.ts***.

At the beginning, in the block of imports, add this import:

```ts
import VisualObjectInstanceEnumeration = powerbi.VisualObjectInstanceEnumeration;
```

Then, at the end, replace the function `enumerateObjectInstances` with:

```ts
public enumerateObjectInstances(options: EnumerateVisualObjectInstancesOptions): VisualObjectInstanceEnumeration {

    var enumeratedObjects: VisualObjectInstanceEnumerationObject =
        <VisualObjectInstanceEnumerationObject>VisualSettings.enumerateObjectInstances(
            this.settings || VisualSettings.getDefault(), options
        );

    if (options.objectName === "YOUR_OBJECT_NAME") {
        enumeratedObjects.instances[0].validValues = {
            YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME: { numberRange: { min: 8, max: 20 } }
        };
    }

    return enumeratedObjects;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the new FormattingModel utils ( powerbi-visuals-utils-formattingmodel ) you can use the following in the settings.ts:

```
myNumericSlice = new formattingSettings.NumUpDown({
    name: "myNumericSlice",
    displayName: "My Formatting Numeric Slice",
    value: 50,
    visible: true,
    options: {
        minValue: {
            type: powerbi.visuals.ValidatorType.Min,
            value: 0,
        },
        maxValue: {
            type: powerbi.visuals.ValidatorType.Max,
            value: 100,
        },
    }
});
```

Microsoft Docs:

```
https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-visuals-utils-formattingmodel
```